# Compiler error when one generic extends another

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors

Does anyone know why the following MWE won't compile (though it shows as no errors in Intellij)?

```
public class Test {
    public interface Inner {
    }

    public interface Middle<T> {
    }

    public interface Outer<T extends Middle<?>> {
    }

    public static class InnerImpl implements Inner {
    }

    public static class MiddleImpl<T extends U, U extends Inner> implements Middle<U> {
    }

    public static class OuterImpl implements Outer<MiddleImpl<? extends InnerImpl, ? super InnerImpl>> {
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following under both Java 8 and 17 SDKs (so not a language level issue):

```
java: type argument ? extends Test.InnerImpl is not within bounds of type-variable T
```

The funny thing is if I switch the order of the generics in `MiddleImpl` it works:

```
public static class MiddleImpl<U extends Inner, T extends U> implements Middle<U> {
```

but this isn't an option in reality since `MiddleImpl` comes from an existing library.

Comment: So, if _"? extends InnerImpl"_ is not within the bounds of _T_, then wouldn't _T_ have to encompass _InnerImpl_?

Comment: [It doesn't compile on ideone](https://ideone.com/wHnHOa) with the order of the generics switched on MiddleImpl. (It uses Java 12, fwiw)

Comment: Doesn't compile in Java 8 either. Did you also switch `extends` with `super`? It is odd that that compiles, but I'm guessing the compiler can infer the bounds of `T` when `U` is specified first.

Comment: One of the main concerns here is that wildcard `?`. You would have better functionality using the actual type mentioned there instead of the wildcard.